# php get string length and trim to get only specific string

Tags: php

```
$string = strlen("hello world how are you"); // 23 characters.
if ($string > 11) {
  // code here to get only "hello world"
}
```

I want to get only "hello world". 
What function do I need to use it?

Comment: you want hello world or first two words?

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean. Is it always gonna be hello world or the first 11 chars?

Comment: Q1.-> your string is going to change frequently or will be same always? Q2.->you need to get first 11 character or first two words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `substr()`

```
$string = "hello world how are you";
if (strlen($string) > 11) {
    echo substr($string,0,11); 
}
```

This will result to:

```
hello world
```

Doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: Not a downvoter but OP need to clarify these two:- Q1.-> string is going to change frequently or will be same always? Q2.->need to get first 11 character or first two words?

Comment: Thanks~! Working!

Comment: @wwwrrrxxx Happy to help.

Comment: @AlivetoDie, Yeah you have a point. But OP is using `strlen` so the logic of cutting must be on the on string length. And it is dynamic, coz if it is not, OP could just `echo "Hello World"` directly :)

Comment: @wwwrrrxxx  this answer will not work if first two word length is greater than 11. check here:- https://eval.in/970277

Comment: I think the user is doing something like an *ellipsis*.. And you don't need to have a full word in the end of the text before the `...` (Well, as far as I know) :)